# Allow GUI to stay on screen with Button Press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I make the GUI Labels and Box stay on screen when I press Tab - This code at the moment allows it to appear but when you release Tab it disappears. Thank you

```
public void OnGUI()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab)) 
    {
        GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(1000, 5, 400, 400), "What You Should Know");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(1135, 5, 400, 400), "___________________");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(1145, 23, 400, 400), "<color=cyan><size=20>The </size></color>" + "<color=cyan><size=20>" + this.cdrw + "</size></color>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment the Tab button is released, `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab)` will return `false`. If you want to always show the GUI elements after the first press of Tab, you could instead modify a Boolean flag when `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab)` is `true`, and use that flag as your condition for showing/hiding your GUI. For example:

```
bool showGui = false;

public void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab)) 
    {
        showGui = true;
    }
}

public void OnGUI()
{
    if (showGui) 
    {
        GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(1000, 5, 400, 400), "What You Should Know");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(1135, 5, 400, 400), "___________________");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(1145, 23, 400, 400), "<color=cyan><size=20>The </size></color>" + "<color=cyan><size=20>" + this.cdrw + "</size></color>");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** If you want to toggle the visibility of the GUI with Tab presses, you can use `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)` (which only fires the first frame that Tab is pressed), and change your `Update()` to negate `showGui` each time Tab is pressed:

```
public void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)) 
    {
        showGui = !showGui;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much you genius! :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Anyway I could close it again by pressing <tab>? Sorry for the bother :/

Comment: @Jaindreas Sure! I've added to my answer, hope it helps.